# Using CSV data with cubism.js

Tags: javascript, cubism.js

I am new to [cubism.js](http://square.github.com/cubism/); but would like to use it to plot some CSV data collected and stored at various rates, anywhere from 60hz to average 20hz.

The file format is:

```
"TIMESTAMP","RECORD","Ux","Uy","Uz","Ts"
```

where Ux,y,z is 3d wind speeds, i.e.  north/south, east/west winds, and Ts is temperature.

```
"2011-07-21 07:03:03.1",24640835,0.0055,-0.03925,0.24075,24.18286,0.7445,-1.0425,-0.18225,24.21899,6.16675,-1.3475,0.58375,24.67505,33,27,27
"2011-07-21 07:03:03.15",24640836,0.00575,-0.03325,0.2435,24.19662,0.62075,-1.236,-0.19275,24.24136,6.25275,-1.3685,0.49575,24.70435,34,28,28
"2011-07-21 07:03:03.2",24640837,0.0275,-0.00925,0.22075,24.15018,0.467,-1.28625,-0.2165,24.24478,6.54625,-1.238,0.30025,24.73019,35,29,29
"2011-07-21 07:03:03.25",24640838,0.032,0.0045,0.1975,24.19492,0.50375,-1.307,-0.1965,24.2706,6.552001,-1.45625,0.57125,24.63718,36,30,30
"2011-07-21 07:03:03.3",24640839,0.017,0.00475,0.1775,24.15878,0.457,-1.14025,-0.14825,24.27231,6.407001,-1.223,0.534,24.72845,37,31,31
"2011-07-21 07:03:03.35",24640840,-0.04,0.042,0.154,24.18115,0.43525,-1.06975,-0.072,24.2775,6.39425,-1.1755,0.558,24.71469,38,32,32
"2011-07-21 07:03:03.4",24640841,-0.061,0.06525,0.14375,24.16907,0.59825,-0.8595001,-0.101,24.25513,6.21225,-1.25075,0.5785,24.76633,39,33,33
"2011-07-21 07:03:03.45",24640842,-0.04725,0.072,0.12175,24.16052,0.5330001,-0.7,-0.0815,24.26715,6.17925,-0.8412501,0.3965,24.73706,40,34,34
"2011-07-21 07:03:03.5",24640843,-0.06175,0.06075,0.0865,24.15189,0.58925,-0.74575,0.00525,24.25165,6.263,-0.9675,0.056,24.78186,41,35,35
"2011-07-21 07:03:03.55",24640844,-0.032,0.08575001,0.07300001,24.15878,0.546,-0.77,0.1255,24.29126,6.353,-1.08975,-0.03825,24.76288,42,36,36
```

I can easily read the data in using d3.csv, or other javascript methods; but I am unsure how to format it for cubism.

A Ux positive wind speed would show from bottom up and a negative would show from top down, Uy,Uz would do the same.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Seem to me that you are trying to do two plotting on a single horizon using cubism.js which doesn't seem possible as I was trying to achieve that myself too but I only came to realized that a single horizon only takes in a single value over the time of occurrence but you can always split the Ux and Uy into two different horizons hence you then achieve what you wanted.